# Running three fieldsets side-by-side

Tags: javascript, html, forms, fieldset

I'm currently trying to get three translations of a text to appear side-by-side after selecting them in a drop-down menu. So far, I've got the first menu working no problem, but the second and third aren't cooperating. I assume this is some kind of nesting error, but I can't figure it out. How do I make the javascript work for all three fieldsets?

What I've got:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
 body
 {
  background-image:url('gradient1.jpg');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
 }
.ex
 {
  margin:auto;
  width:90%;
  padding:10px;
  border:outset;
 }
 select
 {
  display:inline;
  cursor:pointer;
 } 
form{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 550px;
}

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="ex">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Select Translation</legend>
                <p>
                <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
                    <option value="scroll">Orignal Greek</option>
                    <option value="tooltip">Original Latin</option>
                    <option value="con_scroll">English Translation</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <p>
                <input type="button" id="showVal" value="Select" />
                </p>    
                <output type="text" size="30" name="display" id="display" />
            </p>

            </fieldset>

        </form>
        <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm2">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Select Translation</legend>
                <p>
                <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
                    <option value="scroll">Orignal Greek</option>
                    <option value="tooltip">Original Latin</option>
                    <option value="con_scroll">English Translation</option>
                </select>
                <br>
            <p>
            <input type="button" id="showVal" value="Select" />
            </p>    
            <output type="text" size="30" name="display" id="display" />
            </p>

    </fieldset>

    </form>
    <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm3">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select Translation</legend>
            <p>
                <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
                    <option value="scroll">Orignal Greek</option>
                    <option value="tooltip">Original Latin</option>
                    <option value="con_scroll">English Translation</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <p>
                <input type="button" id="showVal" value="Select" />
                </p>    
                <output type="text" size="30" name="display" id="display" />
                </p>

        </fieldset>

    </form>
</div>
</body>
<script>
(function() {

    // get references to select list and display text box
    var sel = document.getElementById('scripts');
    var el = document.getElementById('display');



    function getSelectedOption(sel) {
        var opt;
        for ( var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            opt = sel.options[i];
            if ( opt.selected === true ) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return opt;
    }

    // assign onclick handlers to the buttons
    document.getElementById('showVal').onclick = function () {
        el.value = sel.value;    
    }

    document.getElementById('showTxt').onclick = function () {
        // access text property of selected option
        el.value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    }

    document.getElementById('doLoop').onclick = function () {
        var opt = getSelectedOption(sel);
        el.value = opt.value;
    }

}());
// immediate function to preserve global namespace
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution in vanillaJS.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".demoForm"), function(element) {
  element.querySelector("#showVal").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var dropdown = element.querySelector("#scripts");
    var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].text;
    element.querySelector("#display").innerHTML = value;
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="ex">
  <form action="#" method="post" class="demoForm">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Select Translation</legend>
      <p>
        <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
          <option value="scroll">Orignal Greek</option>
          <option value="tooltip">Original Latin</option>
          <option value="con_scroll">English Translation</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <div class="inline">
          <p>
            <input type="button" id="showVal" value="Select" />
          </p>
          <span id="display"></span>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

  </form>
  <form action="#" method="post" class="demoForm">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Select Translation</legend>
      <p>
        <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
          <option value="scroll">Orignal Greek</option>
          <option value="tooltip">Original Latin</option>
          <option value="con_scroll">English Translation</option>
        </select>
        <div class="inline">
          <p>
            <input type="button" id="showVal" value="Select" />
          </p>
          <span id="display"></span>

        </div>
    </fieldset>

  </form>
  <form action="#" method="post" class="demoForm">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Select Translation</legend>
      <p>
        <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
          <option value="scroll">Orignal Greek</option>
          <option value="tooltip">Original Latin</option>
          <option value="con_scroll">English Translation</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <div class="inline">
          <p>
            <input type="button" id="showVal" value="Select" />
          </p>
          <span id="display"></span>

        </div>
    </fieldset>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique, you have 3 elements with the id scripts, and 3 with id showVal.

```
var sel = document.getElementById('scripts')
var el = document.getElementById('display');
```

Returns exactly 1 element, not all elements with the id, I replaced this with

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('#scripts');
var el = document.querySelectorAll('#display');
```

For the 3 with id showVal it looks like you meant to use different ids for each button: `showVal, showTxt, doLoop`

I assume you were attempting to do all three onclicks in a different way?
While I did fix that initially, I chose to refactor the whole code

```js
(function() {

    // get references to select list and display text box
    var sel = document.querySelectorAll('#scripts');
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('#display');
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"');
    
  sel.forEach(function(elem, i){
     buttons[i].onclick = function(e){
       el[i].value = elem.value;
      };
    })
}());
// immediate function to preserve global namespace
```

```css
.ex
 {
  margin:auto;
  width:90%;
  padding:10px;
  border:outset;
 }
 select
 {
  display:inline;
  cursor:pointer;
 } 
form{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 550px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="ex">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Select Translation</legend>
                <p>
                  <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
                      <option value="scroll">Orignal Greek</option>
                      <option value="tooltip">Original Latin</option>
                      <option value="con_scroll">English Translation</option>
                  </select>
                  <br>
                  <p>
                    <input type="button" id="showVal" value="Select" />
                  </p>    
                  <input type="text" size="30" name="display" id="display" />
              </p>

            </fieldset>

        </form>
        <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm2">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Select Translation</legend>
                <p>
                <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
                    <option value="scroll">Orignal Greek</option>
                    <option value="tooltip">Original Latin</option>
                    <option value="con_scroll">English Translation</option>
                </select>
                <br>
            <p>
            <input type="button" id="showTxt" value="Select" />
            </p>    
            <input type="text" size="30" name="display" id="display" />
            </p>

    </fieldset>

    </form>
    <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm3">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select Translation</legend>
            <p>
                <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
                    <option value="scroll">Orignal Greek</option>
                    <option value="tooltip">Original Latin</option>
                    <option value="con_scroll">English Translation</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <p>
                <input type="button" id="doLoop" value="Select" />
                </p>    
                <input type="text" size="30" name="display" id="display" />
                </p>

        </fieldset>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, you're amazing. Thank you so much!